# create parallel gpg

Tags: gpg, parallelism

I am trying to tar, compress and encrypt a large backup folder but the process is slow as I believe gpg is single threaded.
I have been tryping to use split to divide the root folder so instead of encrypting a single larger tar ball I would be doing many.

Is this even possible or what am I doing wrong?

```
tar -I pigz -cf - source \
| gpg -c -o destination  --passphrase-file xyz --batch --no-tty --cipher-algo AES256 --compress-algo none --no-options - 2 \
| split --additional-suffix=.tar.part -b 1G - "backup-test" >>/log.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Pack

```
tar --create --format=posix --preserve-permissions --same-owner --directory $BASE/$name --to-stdout . |
    parallel --pipe --recend '' --keep-order --block-size 128M "xz -9 --check=sha256 | gpg --encrypt --recipient $RECIPIENT;echo bLoCk EnD" |
    pv > $TARGET/$FILENAME
```

Unpack

```
cat $TARGET/$FILENAME |
  parallel --pipe --recend 'bLoCk EnD\n' -N1 --keep-order --rrs 'gpg --decrypt | xz -d' |
  tar tv
```

`-N1` is needed to make sure we pass a single record at a time. GnuPG does not support decrypting multiple merged records.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions Ole.  Further investigation showed the bottleneck to be Amazon lazy loading from S3.  We had attached ebs volume from a snapshot.
This is still slow have managed to speed it up using fio.

echo "File initialisation Starts Now: `date`"
FILES=$(ls -d /mnt/database/files/database_*)
echo $FILES

for f in $FILES
do
echo "Reading file $f"
# This stops any output and lets the process carry on.
sudo fio --opendir="$f" --rw=read --bs=128k --iodepth=32 --ioengine=libaio --direct=1 --name="$f" --openfiles=1000 >/dev/null 2>&1 &

done